# Rails3 with SQLite3::SQLException: no such column HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, has-and-belongs-to-many

Using Sqlite3 with Rails3 and I receive "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column" with a has_and_belongs_to_many situation.  From rails console connected to Sqlite3, errors when page.editors or page.admin_users

[[[EDIT: Solved because of typos in the join table id's]]]

gems installed

rails 3.0.9

sqlite3 1.3.3 x86-mingw32

sqlite3-ruby

(win7 64bit dev machine)

page.rb --> OK

```
> class Page      
>        belongs_to :subject
>        has_many :sections
>        has_and_belongs_to_many :editors, :class_name => "AdminUser"
>        #has_and_belongs_to_many :admin_users
>        
>        end
```

admin_users.rb --> OK

```
>  class AdminUser      
>       has_and_belongs_to_many :pages
>       scope :named, lambda {|first,last| where(:first_name =>
> first, :last_name => last)}
>       
>     end
```

migration file  --> Spot the Typos!

```
    class CreateAdminUsersPagesJoin  false do |t|
          t.integer :admin_users_id, :foreign_key => true  # Should be admin_user_id
          t.integer :page_id, :foreign_key => true
        end
        add_index :admin_users_pages, [:admin_users_id, :page_id]  # Again admin_user_id
      end

      def self.down  
        drop_table :admin_users_pages
      end

    end
```

rails console errors

```
irb(main):004:0> page.admin_users
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: admin_users_pages.admin_user_id: SELECT * FROM "admin_users
" INNER JOIN "admin_users_pages" ON "admin_users".id = "admin_users_pages".admin_user_id WHERE ("admin_users_pages".page_id = 2 )
```

Thanks to Heikki for the posts.  I fixed it myself before looking back here only now (d'oh) but I'll happily accept the answer.  Post it and I'll check it since that was correct.  Cheers.

Comment: Aren't you missing `def self.up` from your migration?

Comment: `:admin_users_id` should probably `:admin_user_id`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  The def self.up is there so I think the stackoverflow missed the paste??   Anyway, I had not only the one typo but two.  I went to sqlite3 and hit .schema admin_users_pages and I saw that the foreign keys were plural so that confirms one comment.  Also note the index is also incorrect as plural.  That I think fixed it.  I made sure sqlite3-ruby was in the Gemfile for the hell of it and ran a bundle update.  Solved it myself but I'll rep Heikki here since that was the issue.  Heikki, I'll update my post and you post your answer and I'll check it.  Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By convention the foreign keys in the join table should be singular ie. `admin_user_id` instead of `admin_users_id`.

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association